# How to Truncate Table in SQLite in CPP?

Tags: c, sqlite

Trying to truncate table but the output is Segmentation fault (core dumped).
Following is my code to truncate.
Table Name : DEPO
Since the function del_depo_data is called from different place and database is opened from where it is called so, didn't write the code to open open DB.

```
void del_depo_data()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;
    const char* data = "Callback function called";

    /* Create merged SQL statement */
    sql = "DELETE FROM TABLE DEPO";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**.

1. Need to Open the DB inside the del_depo_data().
2. In the SQL Query there is a syntactical error.
3. Delete from DEPO will be there.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the function del_depo_data is called from different place and database is opened from where it is called so, didn't write the code to open open DB.

If you've opened a database somewhere else in your code, you need to pass the database handle (the `sqlite3 *`) to this function somehow. As it stands, you're declaring a local variable `sqlite3 *db`, but never initializing it to any value. This causes SQLite to crash.

Additionally, `DELETE FROM TABLE tablename` is not a valid SQLite syntax. The correct syntax is simply `DELETE FROM tablename`.

Comment: closed the db at the calling place and opened it again inside the del_depo_data, this time error is not throwing but table is not getting truncated
@duskwuff